# Callback in javascript don't work for me?

Tags: javascript, callback, xmlhttprequest

iv'e been developping with js lately (yeah im still a beginner) and iv' been wondering about 2 things ?

**1st Thing :**

i discovered that it dosen't wait for a return from a function it moves directly to the next instruction so i was wondering if js was multithreaded ?

And after doing some reasearch i found out that it is event driven that i totally dont get it, if it's not multithreaded then how these called events make js run like that i mean ignoring function and move on until the result is calculated and returned ?

**2nd Thing :**

And i heard about callbacks that supposedly can be used to prevent js from running any code until a certain function completed so i tried it and it dosn't worked that well so here is what i have done :

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <script>

        var j = "Nothing to show";

        function show() {
            console.log(j);
        }

        function dosome(callback) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                    if (xhr.status == 200) {
                        j = xhr.response;
                    } else
                        alert(xhr.status + " : " + xhr.statusText);
                }
            }

            xhr.open("GET", "./index.php", true);
            xhr.send();

            callback();
        }

        dosome(function(){show();});

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

index.php

```
<?php
   sleep(2);
   echo "new Value";
?>
```

and the output is always the same it shows "old value" so what was i doing wrong ?

and thank you.

Comment: you're calling callback immediately, not waiting for `onreadystatechange` - here's how your code could be written https://jsfiddle.net/haoe4gtq/

Comment: you don't get the point if it can prevent code from runiing until another finishes so it will wait for the value from php then it will execute the callback() cause xhr.open will be called and it should be stuck there until the php return the value , but instead went and executed the callback function without waiting

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there

First, how that code could be written

```
function show(result) {
    console.log(result);
}

function dosome(callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if (xhr.status == 200) {
                callback(xhr.response);
            } else
                callback(xhr.status + " : " + xhr.statusText);
        }
    }
    xhr.open("GET", "./index.php", true);
    xhr.send();
}
dosome(show);
```

Now to break it down:

usually, callbacks are called with some argument (the result of the async call)

```
function show(result) {
    console.log(result);
}
```

Second, you need to wait for the async call to complete, so callback should be done in onreadystatechange callback

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        if (xhr.status == 200) {
            callback(xhr.response);
        } else
            callback(xhr.status + " : " + xhr.statusText);
    }
}
```

and finally, you can shorten `function() { show(); }` to just

```
dosome(show);
```

As you are passing the function `show` to the function `dosome` as the callback

Comment: but if we put it like that it will reach the callback when `xhr.readystate == 4` so in other words js will not see the callback function until the php has finished so until `xhr.readystate == 4` but if i understood callbacks correctly i can put it there and js should be stuck in `xhr.send()` until a response is given from php than it executes the callback

Comment: you don't understand callbacks in that case - asynchronous  code means it WONT get *stuck* at xhr.send - that's how asynchrony works

Comment: that's what im trying to know so there is no way that u can run code after another ends even with callbacks is that right?

Comment: Anything you want to run that needs to wait for the asynchronous operation needs to be run in a callback

Comment: Alternatively use promises and async await. That way the code looks, but isn't, synchronous. It's not synchronous but the code looks more like what you are comfortable with

Comment: okay to put it simply can you fix this code so that it show A first before B with a callback ?https://jsfiddle.net/CodeCrator/dj2sLoqb/1/

Comment: How about you try with the knowledge gained from this answer

Comment: that's exactly what im trying to say i still don't get i was hoping with this simpler example i could finaly understand it ? that is if you will do us the honor.